# Problem related with cross ratio in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I  am stuck on the following problem that says :

> The value of the cross-ratio $(7+i,1,0,\infty)$ is which of the following? The options are:
>
> 1. $6+i$
> 2. $-6+i$
> 3. $6-i$
> 4. $-6-i$

My Attempt: The cross ratio of four complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ (with at least three being distinct) is
$$\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)}.$$
Once $z_4$ is $\infty$, we can define the cross ratio by taking limits as
$$(z_1,z_2,z_3,\infty)=\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}.$$

So,using this formula,my answer is $7+i.$ So,where did I go wrong ?

Can someone help? Thanks in advance for your time .

Comment: I believe you are right. Maybe they meant $(7+i,0,1,\infty)$... Anyway, your answer is correct

Comment: I get $7+i$ as well. Probably a typo in the problem.

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different conventions for the cross ratio. The two that I am familiar with, and that are common, are

1. $\operatorname{CR}(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)$ maps $z_1 \mapsto 0;\; z_2 \mapsto 1;\; z_3 \mapsto \infty$, and
2. $\operatorname{CR}(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)$ maps $z_1 \mapsto 1;\; z_2 \mapsto 0;\; z_3 \mapsto \infty$.

Evidently you learned the second convention, and apparently the poser of the exercise used the first convention (or possibly an uncommon one).

Under the first convention, $\operatorname{CR}(z,1,0,\infty)$ is the Möbius transformation that swaps $0$ and $1$ and leaves $\infty$ fixed, i.e. $z \mapsto 1-z$. Then $\operatorname{CR}(7+i,1,0,\infty) = 1 - (7+i) = -6 -i$.